# Making refresh token api call every 60 minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

I currently have a refresh token api call in the function 'refreshToken()', which isn't shown in the below code but can be added if needed. In the root component's componentDidMount function I call refreshToken() with the purpose it will execute every 60 minutes. Not sure whether to use setInterval or setTimeout in this instance as I also store the tokens in localStorage. I'm also using the Spotify API and their OAuth that passes me the refresh and access tokens. I also realize I would need the token expiration time in localstorage so the timer doesn't reset on page reload, so how should I go about that as well? Below is the code I currently have.

App.js (root component)

```
componentDidMount(){
    var now = new Date();
    var delay = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour in msec
    var start = delay - (now.getMinutes() * 60 + now.getSeconds()) * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds();

    setTimeout(function() {
      setTimeout(refreshToken(), delay);
    }, start);

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('spotifyAccessToken')){
      this.getSpotifyData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount()` is only executed once ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)) when the component mounts.
You have to use `setInterval()` to schedule it periodically.

And **don't** forget to cancel the timer in `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
componentDidMount(){
   var delay = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour in msec

   this.timer = setInterval(
     () => refreshToken(),
           delay,
   );
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: I just realized this issue using the code you sent, if the user refreshes the page, the timer is set back to 1. But the tokens expiration will remain decreasing from wherever it is. How do I account for that as well?

Comment: storing this.timer in local storage im assuming?